# Is it possible to get negative (True Negative)?

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy, graph-theory, confusion-matrix

I have 3600 samples as my dataset. I split the dataset into the train (2700) and test (900).

My problem is related to `new link prediction`. I am using the Common Neighbor (CN) method. Using CN, we can predict new links based on the score. The score comes from the CN formula. CN gives a score for every possible edge/path/link. A higher score means a higher possibility to be a new link.

Now, I applied my train dataset to the CN methods. From CN, I have received 4200 new links with a score. From this 4200, I took only the top 1% (based on the score given by CN). So, the top 1% is 42.

Now, I tried to match the 42 with my test dataset. Means, actually, how many edges/links/path I can recover which were missing in the training dataset.

Among these 42 (CN output), 38 samples are perfectly matched with the test dataset (means same edge/link/path of the train and test). But, I did not give or these 38 edges/link/paths were missing in the training dataset.

So,

```
True Positive: 38
False Positive: 42-38 = 04
False Negative: 900-38 = 862
True Negative: 900 - (38 + 04 + 862) = -04
```

Now, I would like to know, is it possible to get negative (True Negative)? Or I am doing something wrong?

How, can I reduce the value of `False Negative` and increase the value of `True Negative`.

Comment: FPs sound impossible in this data. Try writing down the confusion matrix, starting with the margins. Maybe the process will be clearer for you, and for us it will clarify how you got these numbers.

Comment: Why you are thinking FP is impossible in this data? My model predicts 42 output. I cam match 38 (TP). Among 42, 4 are predicted as positive but these 4 are not matched with the test dataset. So they are FP, right? Or maybe I am not sure, what you mean!

Comment: If all true labels are indeed "positive" in your sample, then every "positive" prediction by your model is correct: i.e. FPs are impossible. I do not really understand what you mean by "matching", so I suggest you edit the question to add this information - this might help me or others to answer.

Comment: Edited and let me know if you have any questions.